# Service Provider with issuer not registered

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I tried creating a service provider with issuer carbonServer in Identity server carbon console.
I tried enabling SAMLSSO Authenticator in authenticators.xml  at /repository/conf/security/ directory
When I start the service and access the carbon console I get this error.

SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing authentication request!
Please try login again!

In the logs I get this error
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} -  A SAML Service Provider with the Issuer 'IS_MGT_CONSOLE' is not registered. Service Provider should be registered in advance

The registered Service Provider name is IS_MGT_CONSOLE and issuer is carbonServer. 
Any idea what could the reason for this error  and the Issuer in the error getting listed as Service Provider?

Answer (score 1):

Please check 'ServiceProviderID' in authenticators.xml -> SAML2SSOAuthenticator. By default it is 'carbonServer' and it should be same as Issuer value in (Inbound Authentication Configuration) --> (SAML SSO Configuration).

I suspect even though you registered SAML issuer as carbonSever, SAML auth request come as IS_MGT_CONSOLE. You should be able to correct it by modifying 'ServiceProviderID' to carbonSever